# Google Mobile Ads SDK 19.2.0 or higher not working with kivy/buildozer

Tags: python, android, gradle, kivy, buildozer

Good day. I've built a python/kivy app and I included ads using the google mobile ads sdk 16.0.0 which works fine and shows ads in the app (when I used testIds and my own app IDs). I tried to release the app on google play store and it states that ads sdk versions 19.2.0 or higher should be used for displaying ads since anything lower than that won't be supported soon. I tried putting in the recommended versions or higher and build the app again but it doesn't work (I've tried almost all the versions stated on the official website). It states that gradlew failed for some versions when building app with buildozer or if the version works and app builds successfully, ads don't show. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance...

versions
...........
Gradle 8.0-rc-2
openjdk 17.0.5 2022-10-18
python 3.11.0

My buildozer .spec file details

## (list) Gradle dependencies to add

android.gradle_dependencies =com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0, com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0

Answer (score 0):

> You are using Gradle too advanced version which might be not compatible to some dependencies, so use **Gradle version 7.5** (stable version for android developments these days).